# Entity Framework Database.ExecuteSqlCommand update randomly drops

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 Database.ExecuteSqlCommand to execute some raw SQL updates in the database, this seems like a pretty simple and straight forward task. However, it has happened a few times that some of the update statements would not execute, randomly. The application is being used actively each day and more than 10,000 rows can be inserted/updated in a day, but there were two times that ONE update seemed did not run, and one time there were about 20 updates seemed did not run.

Consider the following use case:

A model named Trip, each Trip in the same group needs to have a foreign key to the previous Trip and the next Trip.

There are about 5000 trips that need to be inserted into the database. For import these Trips I need to insert them as fast as possible, so I'm using SqlBulkCopy to do the task. As a result, I can't populate the foreign keys during insert, so I will have to update each row afterwards. To do that I load all trips back from the database after the bulk copy is done then loop through them and execute an update to set the foreign keys.

The code would look like this:

```
// ... after SqlBulkCopy is done
string tripGroup = null;
Trip previousTrip = null;

foreach (Trip trip in trips)
{
    if (tripGroup != trip.TripGroup)
    {
        tripGroup = trip.TripGroup;
        previousTrip = null;
    }

    if (previousTrip != null)
    {
        uow.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [Trips] SET PrevTripId = {0} WHERE Id = {1}", previousTrip.Id, trip.Id);
        uow.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [Trips] SET NextTripId = {0} WHERE Id = {1}", trip.Id, previousTrip.Id);
    }
    previousTrip = trip;
}
```

The table would look like this:

[image]

The problem is sometimes the PrevTripId and NextTripId will not be populated. This has only happened on the server, I cannot reproduce this issue on my local dev machine. It's worth to point out that in production the application server and the sql server are separated. I tried putting the code in a loop to run 50 times while constantly taking a db backup, running selects, etc., but I got no luck.

The only thing I can think of for now is to monitor the result and do some logging just so I can see when it can happen. But I'll have to wait until it happens again.

Any idea what could have caused the issue or any suggestion on how to recreate/debug this issue is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using an ORM if you want to execute SQL commands against the database? In fact, you *shouldn't* be using an ORM to perform batch updates. A single `UPDATE` statement will perform the same job as  the 2*N individual updates, at ~ 2*N times the speed

Comment: How do you determine the values of PrevTripID, NextTripId? You can use the `LAG`, `LEAD` T-SQL functions to access the next/previous trip/leg in a journey. eg `LAG(Id,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TripGroup ORDER BY ...)  as PrevTripId, LEAD(Id,1,NULL, OVER (PARTITION BY TripGroup ORDER BY ...)  as NextTripId`

Comment: well, first of all, consider what @PanagiotisKanavos says, agree 100%, then supposing you have good reasons to use an ORM, it looks like you have to implement some logging to find out what's happening, I can think of several things, but one that sets off the alarms is mixing updates through DbContext and SQL, you might have a case of "lost update" (the first overwriting the latter so it seems like it didn't happen). Also bear in mind that the two SQL updates are TWO separate transactions, and it looks to me like they should be just one.

Answer (score 0):

ORMs are unsuitable for batch operations, whether these involve bulk loading or batch updates. This code though bypasses the ORM itself to send 2 UPDATE statements per row, resulting in 2N operations *plus* loading all the data in memory.

It's a lot simpler, faster and *safer* to perform batch operations using SQL. A couple of SQL statements can update all rows in a single transaction without loading anything on the client.

In this case, you can take advantage of the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) analytical functions to retrieve the previous/next value in a partition.

Assuming that the trips are ordered by ID and partitioned by TripGroup, you can retrieve the previous/next IDs with :

```
select 
    id,
    LAG(ID,1,null) OVER (Partition by TripGroup order by id) as PrevTripID,
    LEAD(ID,1,null) OVER (Partition by TripGroup order by id) as NextTripId
from Trips;
```

This will return the same results as those posted in the picture.

To update Trips, you need to use a CTE, since analytical functions can only be used in a SELECT statement:

```
with ids as (
select 
    id,
    LAG(ID,1,null) OVER (Partition by TripGroup order by id) as PrevTripID,
    LEAD(ID,1,null) OVER (Partition by TripGroup order by id) as NextTripId
from Trips
)
update t
set
    PevTripId =ids.PrevTripID,
    NextTripId =ids.NextTripId 
from Trips t inner join ids on ids.Id=t.id;
```

Instead of loading 5000 rows and executing 10000 commands, you only need a single statement.